# MVC Action not returning csv file. ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv

I want to get data from database and show it in CSV file. Following is my code for getting data from db.

```
public ActionResult GetTNStateUnemploymentReport(int quarter, int year, int payrollState, long? fromClientId, long? toClientId, string fromClient, string toClient)
{
//if (fromClient == "" && toClient == "")
//{
//    fromClientId = 0;
//    toClientId = 0;
//}

string quarterMonths = "";
if (quarter == 1)
    quarterMonths = "Jan, Feb, Mar";
else if (quarter == 2)
    quarterMonths = "Apr, May, Jun";
else if (quarter == 3)
    quarterMonths = "Jul, Aug, Sep";
else if (quarter == 4)
    quarterMonths = "Oct, Nov, Dec";

var modelList = new PayrollHelper().GetTNStateUnemploymentReport(quarter, year, fromClientId ?? 0, toClientId ?? 0);
var csv = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (var model in modelList)
{
    csv.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}", model.StringData, Environment.NewLine));
}

return new CSVResult
{
    FileName = "TN_" + quarterMonths + "_" + year.ToString() + ".csv",
    Content = csv.ToString()
};
```

Following is my `CSVResult` class which I am using to create the CSV File.

```
public class CSVResult: ActionResult
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/csv;charset=utf-8";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(Content);
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> LOCAL HOST SENT INVALID RESPONSE
>   ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION.

I have another report which creates CSV file using above mentioned `ExecuteResult` method and is working fine, but the current one is not.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Check that the filename does not include any illegal characters that will cause the disposition to return that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code  `"TN_" + quarterMonths + "_" + year.ToString() + ".csv"` a file name would look like this

```
"TN_Jul, Aug, Sep_2016.csv"
```

which, based on `.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName)` would result in a content disposition that looks like this

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TN_Jul, Aug, Sep_2016.csv"
```

The commas and spaces in the filename when generating the content disposition will cause issues with some browsers.

Now there are a few ways to fix this.

**1) You could change the way you generate the filename to replace spaces and commas `(,)` with underscores `(_)`**

for example instead of

```
quarterMonths = "Jan, Feb, Mar";
```

change them to

```
quarterMonths = "Jan_Feb_Mar";
```

resulting in a filename that looks like

```
"TN_Jul_Aug_Sep_2016.csv"
```

**2) You could also make sure to enclose the filename in `""` (double quotes)**

So instead of

```
.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName)
```

change it to

```
.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"");
```

or

```
.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", FileName));
```

UPDATE:

Using ideas from the source code for [System.Web.Mvc.FileResult](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileResult.cs) You could rewrite your `CsvResult` to allow for the suggested changes I mentioned above.

```
public class CsvResult : ActionResult {
    private const string CONTENT_TYPE = "application/csv;charset=utf-8";
    private string filename;

    public CsvResult() {
        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue headerValue = null;
        if (System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(CONTENT_TYPE, out headerValue)) {
            ContentType = headerValue.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string ContentType { get; private set; }

    public string FileName {
        get { return filename ?? String.Empty; }
        set { filename = value; }
    }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        HttpResponseBase response = null;
        if (context != null
            && context.HttpContext != null
            && ((response = context.HttpContext.Response) != null)) {

            response.Buffer = true;
            response.Clear();

            response.ContentType = ContentType;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName)) {
                string headerValue = ContentDispositionUtil.GetHeaderValue(FileName);
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
            }

            response.Write(Content);
            response.End();
        }
    }

    internal static class ContentDispositionUtil {
        public static string GetHeaderValue(string filename) {
            System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            string headerValue = String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", filename);
            if (System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(headerValue, out contentDisposition)) {
                var result = contentDisposition.ToString();
                return result;
            } else {
                throw new ArgumentException("Content Disposition Header Value not well formatted - " + headerValue, "FileName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, i used \" \"" in the file name. THanks

Comment: @UzairAshraf, If this resolves your issue, then you can mark as answered.

Comment: You click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use standard result deriving from `FileResult` instead?

[FileResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

One of the 3 concrete classes should do what you want. If you write your own `ActionResult` then it is up to you to write correct code.

Comment: I think this is a really good answer. Show a snippet of how they should use it.

Comment: By reading the documentation, it should not be hard to figure out the possibilities and select the one that best fit...